# Log In procedure not working in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

My table contain only two row. When i am giving empid and password of another row stil login is done. This is my procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE prco_LoginCheck(Emp_Id    IN number,
                                            Cpassword In varchar2,
                                            cur_out   out Types.cursor_type) AS

BEGIN

  open cur_out for


    select count(*) from TBL_REGISTRATION a 
    where a.confirm_password= Cpassword and a.emp_id=Emp_Id;

END prco_LoginCheck;
```

Comment: The variable name Emp_id matches with the column name. Note that case doesnt matter here. Change it. It becomes, like 1=1 and result will be wrong, just checking if there is a matching password.. Disregarding user id.

Comment: i did the changes but it didn't work..

Comment: Thanks Maheswaran Ravisankar it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from the fact that storing a password in a table is a horribly insecure design (you should only be storing a hash of the password plus some random salt), and the fact that it doesn't make a lot of sense to define your own weak ref cursor type rather than using the built-in `sys_refcursor` (unless you really need to work with ancient versions of Oracle), and that returning a cursor from a procedure seems like a really odd way to do a login rather than writing a function that returns a `boolean` or some indicator, the problem is one of naming conventions.

When you write the SQL statement

```
 select count(*) 
   from TBL_REGISTRATION a 
  where a.confirm_password= Cpassword 
    and a.emp_id=Emp_Id;
```

I assume that your intention is to compare the `emp_id` column in `tbl_registration` to the `emp_id` parameter.  That is not actually what is happening, however.  Your unqualified `emp_id` is resolved as a column in the table not the parameter.  Normally, people use a naming convention to ensure that parameter names don't match column names.  I, for example, generally use a `p_` prefix for parameters and `l_` for local variables.  That would look something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE prco_LoginCheck(p_Emp_Id    IN number,
                                            p_password  In varchar2,
                                            p_cur_out   out Types.cursor_type) AS

BEGIN

  open p_cur_out for
     select count(*) 
       from TBL_REGISTRATION a 
      where a.confirm_password= p_password 
        and a.emp_id=p_Emp_Id;

END prco_LoginCheck;
```

It is also possible to use your existing parameter names and just fully qualify the `emp_id` to force it to resolve to the parameter name

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE prco_LoginCheck(Emp_Id    IN number,
                                            Cpassword In varchar2,
                                            cur_out   out Types.cursor_type) AS

BEGIN

  open cur_out for
     select count(*) 
       from TBL_REGISTRATION a 
      where a.confirm_password= Cpassword 
        and a.emp_id=prco_LoginCheck.Emp_Id;

END prco_LoginCheck;
```

Comment: Thanks justin it work and thank you for suggestion in naming convention i will keep in mind.